# Inputs required in python on csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem and need to solve it using Pandas/Python.
Not sure how to achieve it and would be great if someone help here to build the logic.

I have to generate the output file as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'priority': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                  'db_name': ['corp', 'corp', 'corp', 'sales', 'sales', 'market'],
                   'tbl_name': ['c_tbl1', 'c_tbl1', 'c_tbl1', 's_tbl1', 's_tbl2', 'm_tbl1'],
                   'partition': ['202301', '202302', '202303', '202301', '202302', '202301'],
                   'size_gb': [5, 5, 10, 1, 2, 3]})
```

Logic would be like this for priority 1 - three entries presents with different sizes, if the size is 10 GB single entry in output file with t_size = XL or sump of the size create single entry with t_size = XL similarly for other priorities size is less than 3 GB then t_size = S otherwise M.

I tried to loop using Pandas data frames, couldn't proceed as I am not proficient in Python.

Comment: 1. check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
2. be sure to include code samples and, stack traces, and errors

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
df = pd.read_csv("F:\\sales_data.csv", header=0)
  
df = pd.DataFrame(df.pivot_table(
        index=['priority', 'db_name', 'tbl_name'],
        values=['partition', 'size_gb'],
        aggfunc={'partition': lambda x: ";".join(str(v) for v in x), 'size_gb': 'sum'}).to_records())
df['t_size'] = np.where(df['size_gb'] >= 10, 'XL',
                        np.where(df['size_gb'] < 3, 'S', 'M'))
    
df.drop(columns=['size_gb'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  priority  db_name tbl_name    partition   t_size
0   1        corp   c_tbl1    202301;202302  XL
1   1        corp   c_tbl1    202303         XL
2   2        sales  s_tbl1    202301         S
3   2        sales  s_tbl2    202302         S
4   3        market m_tbl1    202301         M
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this, its not working with following data. I put data into csv file.

Comment: import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("F:\\sales_data.csv", header=0)
print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.pivot_table(
    index=['priority', 'db_name', 'tbl_name', 'size_gb'],
    values=['partition', 'size_gb'],
    aggfunc={'partition': lambda x: ";".join(str(v) for v in x), 'size_gb': 'sum'}).rename(
    columns={'size_gb': 'sum_gb'}).to_records())
df['t_size'] = np.where(df['sum_gb'] >= 10, 'XL',
                        np.where(df['sum_gb'] < 3, 'S', 'M'))

df.drop(columns=['size_gb', 'sum_gb'], inplace=True)
print(df)

Comment: Input and output:

Comment: priority,db_name,tbl_name,partition,size_gb
1,market,tbl_market,202301,10
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202301,5
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202302,5
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202303,10
1,corp,tbl_corp2,202301,10
1,corp,tbl_corp3,202302,5
1,corp,tbl_corp3,202303,3
1,corp,tbl_corp3,202304,2
2,sales,tbl_sales1,202301,1
3,sales,tbl_sales2,202302,5

Comment: above one is input data in coma separated format

Comment: priority,db_name,tbl_name,partition,size_gb
1,market,tbl_market,202301,10
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202301,5
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202302,5
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202303,10
1,corp,tbl_corp2,202301,10
1,corp,tbl_corp3,202302,5
1,corp,tbl_corp3,202303,3
1,corp,tbl_corp3,202304,2
2,sales,tbl_sales1,202301,1
3,sales,tbl_sales2,202302,5

Comment: Getting this one

Comment: priority,db_name,tbl_name,partition,t_size
1,market,tbl_market,202301,XL
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202301;202302,XL
1,corp,tbl_corp1,202303,XL
1,corp,tbl_corp2,202301,XL
1,corp,tbl_corp3,202302;202303;202304,XL
2,sales,tbl_sales1,202301,S
3,sales,tbl_sales2,202302,M

Comment: expected output

Comment: Try my new variant, i was update my answer

Comment: Put those details in the question, not in comments to an answer.