# issue in csv file parsing in manipulating column values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am parsing CSV file and output is not as expected.

Input:

| priority | db_name | tbl_name | partition | size_gb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | market | tbl_market | 202301 | 10 |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp1 | 202301 | 5 |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp1 | 202302 | 5 |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp1 | 202303 | 10 |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp2 | 202301 | 10 |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp3 | 202302 | 5 |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp3 | 202303 | 3 |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp3 | 202304 | 2 |
| 2 | sales | tbl_sales1 | 202301 | 1 |
| 3 | sales | tbl_sales2 | 202302 | 5 |

Expected Output:

| priority | db_name | tbl_name | partition | t_size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | market | tbl_market | 202301 | XL |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp1 | 202301;202302 | XL |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp1 | 202303 | XL |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp2 | 202301 | XL |
| 1 | corp | tbl_corp3 | 202302;202303;202304 | XL |
| 2 | sales | tbl_sales1 | 202301 | S |
| 3 | sales | tbl_sales2 | 202302 | M |

Following is the code that I have tried.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("F:\\sales_data.csv", header=0)
print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.pivot_table(
    index=['priority', 'db_name', 'tbl_name', 'size_gb'],
    values=['partition', 'size_gb'],
    aggfunc={'partition': lambda x: ";".join(str(v) for v in x), 'size_gb': 'sum'}).rename(
    columns={'size_gb': 'sum_gb'}).to_records())
df['t_size'] = np.where(df['sum_gb'] >= 10, 'XL',
                np.where(df['sum_gb'] < 3, 'S', 'M'))

df.drop(columns=['size_gb', 'sum_gb'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Ran the above code but output is not as expected. appreciate any inputs

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Show us the actual output.

Comment: priority db_name    tbl_name      partition t_size
0         1    corp   tbl_corp1  202301;202302     XL
1         1    corp   tbl_corp1         202303     XL
2         1    corp   tbl_corp2         202301     XL
3         1    corp   tbl_corp3         202304      S
4         1    corp   tbl_corp3         202303      M
5         1    corp   tbl_corp3         202302      M
6         1  market  tbl_market         202301     XL
7         2   sales  tbl_sales1         202301      S
8         3   sales  tbl_sales2         202302      M

Comment: This is the output I am getting

Comment: please, edit your post and put the final output there

Comment: priority db_name    tbl_name      partition t_size
       1    corp   tbl_corp1  202301;202302     XL
       1    corp   tbl_corp1         202303     XL
       1    corp   tbl_corp2         202301     XL
       1    corp   tbl_corp3         202304      S
       1    corp   tbl_corp3         202303      M
       1    corp   tbl_corp3         202302      M
       1  market  tbl_market         202301     XL
       2   sales  tbl_sales1         202301      S
       3   sales  tbl_sales2         202302      M

Comment: expected output as follows

Comment: Edit the question and add the output there.  It's very hard to read formatted output in a comment.

Comment: priority db_name tbl_name partition t_size
1 market tbl_market 202301 XL
1 corp tbl_corp1 202301;202302 XL
1 corp tbl_corp1 202303 XL
1 corp tbl_corp2 202301 XL
1 corp tbl_corp3 202302;202303;202304 XL
2 sales tbl_sales1 202301 S
3 sales tbl_sales2 202302 M

Comment: sorry, is there a way to share in excel format

Comment: Just click the edit link below your post and add the extra output.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: just now added expected output image

Comment: I'm not sure I see any difference between the expected output and the actual output.  Can you say what is different about the actual output?

Comment: following is the output i am getting, sharing in coma delimitter

Comment: priority ,db_name ,   tbl_name,     partition ,t_size
1,   corp ,  tbl_corp1, 202301;202302 ,    XL
1,   corp ,  tbl_corp1,202303,    XL
1,   corp ,  tbl_corp2,202301,    XL
1,   corp ,  tbl_corp3,202304,     S
1,   corp ,  tbl_corp3,202303,     M
1,   corp ,  tbl_corp3,202302,     M
1, market , tbl_market,202301,    XL
2,  sales , tbl_sales1,202301,     S
3,  sales , tbl_sales2,202302,     M

Comment: output is not as expected for tbl_name: tbl_corp3

Comment: Logic would be like this for priority 1 - three entries presents with different sizes, if the size is 10 GB single entry in output file with t_size = XL or sump of the size create single entry with t_size = XL similarly for other priorities size is less than 5 GB then t_size = M otherwise S.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inputs requierd in python on csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407013/inputs-requierd-in-python-on-csv-files)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your expected output is correct...

```py
df.partition = df.partition.astype(str)

df = (
    df.groupby(['priority', 'db_name', 'tbl_name'], as_index=False)
      .agg({"partition": ";".join, "size_gb": "sum"})
      .rename(columns={"size_gb": "sum_gb"})
)

df['t_size'] = np.select(
    [df.sum_gb.ge(10), df.sum_gb.lt(3)], 
    ['XL', 'S'], 
    'M',
)
df = df.drop("sum_gb", axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   priority db_name    tbl_name             partition t_size
0         1    corp   tbl_corp1  202301;202302;202303     XL
1         1    corp   tbl_corp2                202301     XL
2         1    corp   tbl_corp3  202302;202303;202304     XL
3         1  market  tbl_market                202301     XL
4         2   sales  tbl_sales1                202301      S
5         3   sales  tbl_sales2                202302      M
```